# React: Continuously Change Element onMouseEnter

Tags: reactjs, while-loop, mouseevent

This is my first post, sorry if this has already been answered.

I am trying to continuously update a button element using React while onMouseEnter until the mouse exits. The code I made below does something similar to what I want but it doesn't continuously update on mouseEnter it just updates once per mouseEnter. Instead it should just keep shuffling through bootstrap button styles in order from default to link and then back to default until mouse exit. Just like in the code below the change should stop on exit and continue in the same place once hovered over again. Seriously any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var count = 0;


class ColorButton extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {hover: false};
  this.changeStuff = this.changeStuff.bind(this);
  this.fixStuff = this.fixStuff.bind(this);
  this.setMessage = this.setMessage.bind(this);
}

  changeStuff(){
    this.setState(
      {
        hover: true
      }
    );
  }

  fixStuff(){
    this.setState(
      {
        hover: false
      }
    );
  }


  render() {
    var classes = 'btn btn-default';
    var name = "Default";
    if(this.state.hover == true)
    {
      if(count==0)
      {
        classes = 'btn btn-primary';
        name = "Primary";
        count++;
      }
      else if(count==1)
      {
        classes='btn btn-success';
        name = "Success";
        count++;
      }
      else if(count==2)
      {
        classes='btn btn-info';
        name = "Info";
        count++;
      }
      else if(count==3)
      {
        classes='btn btn-warning';
        name = "Warning";
        count++;
      }
      else if(count==4)
      {
        classes='btn btn-danger';
        name = "Danger";
        count++;
      }
      else if(count==5){
        classes='btn btn-link';
        name = 'Link';
        count++;
      }
      else
      {
        classes='btn btn-default';
        name='Default';
        count = 0;
      }
    }
    return(
      <button className={classes} onMouseOver={this.changeStuff}>{name}</button>
    );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<ColorButton />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're having two issues. First is that you're assuming rendering is happening every second. Rendering only happens when you either call `setState`, or when props change. Easiest way to do that is to do that is to set a timeout on mouseenter that calls `setState` every second. Second is that you're creating "side-effects" in your render function. In react, we never want our render functions to manipulate external values because we never know for sure when render will be called. Try this. I've created an interval that updates the count every second and then uses that value in the render function which gets called every time setState is called.

```
class ColorButton extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { count: 0 };
    this.changeStuff = this.changeStuff.bind(this);
    this.fixStuff = this.fixStuff.bind(this);
    this.setMessage = this.setMessage.bind(this);
  }

  changeStuff() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
    }, 1000);
  }

  fixStuff(){
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.setState({ count: 0 });
  }


  render() {
    var classes = 'btn btn-default';
    var name = "Default";
    if (count === 0) {
      classes = 'btn btn-primary';
      name = "Primary";
    } else if (count === 1) {
      classes = 'btn btn-success';
      name = "Success";
    } else if (count === 2) {
      classes='btn btn-info';
      name = "Info";
    } else if (count === 3) {
      classes='btn btn-warning';
      name = "Warning";
    } else if (count === 4) {
      classes='btn btn-danger';
      name = "Danger";
    } else if (count === 5) {
      classes='btn btn-link';
      name = 'Link';
    } else {
      classes='btn btn-default';
      name='Default';
    }
    return(
      <button className={classes} onMouseOver={this.changeStuff}>{name}</button>
    );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<ColorButton />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've refactored Your code to the code below. It updates the state with new values for class and name every 1 second. You can control the time in the interval function.

```
import React from 'react'

const buttonsData = [
  {
    classes:'btn btn-primary',
    name:'Primary',
  },
  {
    classes:'btn btn-success',
    name:'Success',
  },
  {
    classes:'btn btn-info',
    name:'Info',
  },
  {
    classes:'btn btn-warning',
    name:'Warning',
  },
  {
    classes:'btn btn-danger',
    name:'Danger',
  },
  {
    classes:'btn btn-link',
    name:'Link',
  },
  {
    classes:'btn btn-default',
    name:'Default',
  },

]

class ColorButton extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hover: false,
      classes: 'btn btn-default',
      name: 'Default'
    };
  }

  onHover = () => {
    this.setState({
      hover: true,
    }, this.intervalFunction)
  }

  intervalFunction = () => {
    const dataLen = buttonsData.length
    let index = 0
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      index = index === dataLen ? 0 : index
      if(this.state.hover) {
        this.setState({
          classes: buttonsData[index].classes,
          name: buttonsData[index].name
        })
      }
      index++
    }, 1000)
  }

  onHoverOut = () => {
    this.setState({
      hover: false,
    }, () => clearInterval(this.intervalId))
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <button
        className={this.state.classes}
        onMouseOver={this.onHover}
        onMouseOut={this.onHoverOut}>
        {this.state.name}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ColorButton />, document.getElementById('app'));
```